# Convert date string to another date string format

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime, strftime

I am trying to convert a string datetime to another string time i.e... `May 4, 2021` but I am getting the following error

```
#convert '2021-05-04T05:55:43.013-0500' ->>> May 4, 2021

timing = '2021-05-04T05:55:43.013-0500'
ans = timing.strftime(f'%Y-%m-%d 'f'%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Here is the error

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you import `datetime`? Also you'll want to parse the original string into an object with `datetime.strptime()` first, then use `datetime.strftime()` to get it to the format you want.

Comment: @chemicalwill yes, i imported datetime. how do i parse the string to a datetime object? can you help me here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `datetime.strptime()` not `timing.strftime()`. `timing` is a string that doesn't have any functions called `strftime`. The `datetime` class of the `datetime` module<sup>I know, it's confusing</sup>, OTOH, does have a function to parse a string into a datetime object. Then, *that datetime object* has a function `strftime()` that will format it into a string!

```
from datetime import datetime

timing = '2021-05-04T05:55:43.013-0500'

dtm_obj = datetime.strptime(timing, f'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')

formatted_string = dtm_obj.strftime('%b %d, %Y')
print(formatted_string)
# Outputs:
# May 04, 2021
```